# Как получить все параметры запуска ansible-скрипта в переменную?

Tags: ansible

Есть различные скрипты ansible и у них различные параметры запуска. Можно ли как-то с помощью ansible получить хотя бы в виде строки все параметры, с которыми он был запущен?

Comment: Уточните что вы имеете в виду под "скриптами"  есть таски, есть роли, есть плейбуки - скриптов нет.